# Value of dropdown append in between a text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to append the value of a dropdown in between a text. I have a dropdown with names. when I select a value of the dropdown, I want it to append it in between Dear and Team, as my code shows.

I have tried with this code.

```
<select id="dropbank" name="" class="form-control-sm" onchange="BankSel">
                        <option value=""> Albert House </option>
                        <option value=""> Johnson corp </option>
                        <option value=""> Elementry Homes </option>
                        
                    </select>
                    
                    <textarea id="mailcon" name="" rows="10" cols="" class="form-control" aria-label="" readonly >
                Dear &lt;select&gt; Team,

                Trust this meets you well.
                Warm Regards,

                </textarea>
                
                
function BankSel(dropbank)
{
    
    var mytextarea = document.getElementById('mailcon');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropbank');
    
    mytextarea.value = mytextarea.value + this.value;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as shown below.
Note than you need to remove all `value=""` from your `<option>`s

```js
function BankSel() {
  var mytextarea = document.getElementById('mailcon');
  var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropbank');
  const template = `Dear ${mydropdown.value} Team, 
                    Trust this meets you well.
                    Warm Regards`

  mytextarea.value = template;
}
BankSel();
```

```html
<select id="dropbank" name="" class="form-control-sm" onchange="BankSel()">
  <option> Albert House </option>
  <option> Johnson corp </option>
  <option> Elementry Homes </option>
</select>

<textarea id="mailcon" name="" rows="10" cols="" class="form-control" aria-label="" readonly>
</textarea>
```